# JAR added to Gradle project but no entry in build.gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, slf4j

I am new to the Java tools and stuff, so please be gentle.

I see that someone has added the [Simple Logging Façade 4 Java (SLF4J)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLF4J) logging capability to a project I am looking at in IntelliJ IDEA. The project is a Gradle project and when I see the **Project Structure -> Module -> Dependencies**, I do see a dependency for the SLF4 jars.

[image]

I also see these listed in the **External Libraries** node in the treeview in the **Project** window.

[image]

However, when I open the build.gradle file, I see no entry for slfj. How is that? How would this library have been added to the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slf4j is a transitive dependency of some other library.

Use `./gradlew dependencies` on the root folder of your project to see the dependencies graph.

Answer (score 1):

`slf4j` ist most likely a transitive dependency of one of the declared dependencies.

To list the dependency tree, you can use `gradlew dependencies`.

To list the dependency tree for a specific configuration, you can use `gradlew dependencies --configuration runtime`.

In your situation you can also use the other way around and use `dependencyInsight` task instead like `gradlew dependencyInsight --configuration runtime --dependency org.slf4j:slf4j-api` to see which declared dependencies depen on the given dependency in the given configuration.